# Dell Monitor Codes: ST, E, and U. What do they mean?

Tags: display

Can someone unpack this for me? From what I can tell, the U stands for "Ultra Sharp", but I cannot figure out the other two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the (exact) naming scheme for Dell monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/1272546/whats-the-exact-naming-scheme-for-dell-monitors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ST** ---> Style (or Stylish)

**E**  ---> Ease

**U**  ---> Ultra Sharp

Comment: Where did you get that info?

Comment: My friend says he read these meanings somewhere but I was not able to find anything in google

Answer (score 3):

I found this link on DELL and it explains what the various codes stand for.  I presume it changes once in a while.
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000131468/identifying-dell-monitor-types-by-their-model-number