# What's the (exact) naming scheme for Dell monitors?

Tags: display, specifications, naming

Dell monitors have cryptic model names/codes such as "U2312f" or "E2318H".

The model names is made up of (at least) four elements:

1. Category (1 character):

   E (Economy) / T (Touch) / P (Professional) / S (Studio) / U (Ultrasharp)
2. Diagonal length in inches (including the bezel if I'm not mistaken)
3. A two-digit number
4. Potential combination of several extra letters - upper or lowercase, e.g. H, M, t, f.

Can someone explain the meaning of components 3 and 4?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_monitors for more clues ...

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Since around 2010 the convention has been:

`[Series][Diagonal][Year][Ratio or Resolution][Features]`

1. `Series`

- `E` - Essential.  Usually TN anti-glare panel, internal power, simple base, 3-year warranty.
- `P` - Professional.  Usually IPS anti-glare panel, internal power, height/rotate base, 3-year warranty.
- `S` - Home & Small Office.  TN, VA, or IPS panel, usually external power, slim base, 1-year warranty.
- `U` - UltraSharp.  IPS anti-glare panel, internal power, height/rotate base, 3-year warranty.
- `UP` - UltraSharp with PremierColor.  Additional colour gamut.
- `AW` - Alienware.  High-end gaming.
- `C` - Commercial displays.  Large format (>50") for conference rooms and classrooms.

2. `Diagonal`

- Two digit diagonal viewable size rounded to the nearest inch; halves rounded up.

3. `Year`

- Two digit year it was released.

4. `Ratio or Resolution` - The first uppercase letter after the digits is most commonly the aspect ratio or QHD/UHD resolution

- `S` - standard ratio (4:3 or 5:4),
- `no letter` - computer widescreen (16:10)
- `H` - HD widescreen (16:9)
- `W` - Ultrawide (21:9)
- `D` - QHD (1440p)
- `Q` - 4K UHD (2160p)
- `K` - 8K UHD (4320p)
- The following have also been the first letter, but either on 16:10 (no letter) or discontinued models:
- `T` - Touch
- `M` - No HDMI (S/U-series only)
- `L` - With HDMI (only used when the same model without HDMI exists)
- `N` - With VGA (only used when the same model without VGA exists)

5. `Features` - The second uppercase letter after the digits can represent a large variety of features such as:

- `C` - USB-C input (DisplayPort alternate mode)
- `X` - HDMI cable included (instead of standard DisplayPort)
- `T` - Touch
- `G` - Nvidia G-Sync / Graphics
- `F` - AMD FreeSync
- `J` - Wireless charging stand
- `Z` - Video conferencing camera
- `A` - Arm included (no stand)
- `E` - Ethernet connection via the RJ45 port
- `S` - Speakers built in

Comment: @einpoklum I'm trying to stick to current monitors.  The convention has continually changed.

Comment: @jason the U2715H is a QCD monitor... I was hoping to figure out the HD version of this but cannot!

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yes, it's QHD, but it's also 16:9.  My guess is that Dell didn't adopt the "D" until 2016: P2416D, UP2516D, S2417DG, U2717D, S2718D, etc.

Comment: @Mr.Boy To clarify, "H" monitors can be different resolutions, e.g. 1366x768, 1600x900, 1920x1080, etc.  These are all 16:9 and "high definition".

Comment: I think `C` as a suffix might mean USB-C input. Example: https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-22-usb-c-monitor-p2219hc/apd/210-aqgd/monitors-monitor-accessories

Comment: Recently found out that `X` feature means a variant with HDMI cable instead of DP cable like: U2419H vs U2419HX See connectivity section here: https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/d1c21595

Comment: @Marie.P. S2719DGF is FreeSync, but it's also "G-Sync Compatible" (which is different than G-Sync...).  Whether the "G" stands for Gaming or G-Sync Compatible is anyone's guess...

Comment: Turns out there is a special page with all the info: https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln317180/identifying-dell-monitor-types-by-their-model-number?lang=en

Comment: There can also be a final `b` character... see [here](https://img.yad2.co.il/Pic/202105/11/3_0/o/y2_3_07449_20210511130520.jpeg?l=7&c=6&w=1024&h=768).

Comment: Needs a bit of updating: `Series` `SE` entry-level, 1 Yr warranty; `Series` `G` gaming, similar to AW with high refresh rates;  `Feature` `W` is curved screen

Comment: @MeTTeO Do you still have access to the support page, for me it only says `This article is permission based. Find another article.`